# Retinues sizes in patch 1.101

Tags: crusader-kings-2

I was playing as Ireland in patch 1.091 (I'm not sure now since I've upgraded yesterday). I'm the King of Ireland, Wales and Scotland now, so I'm pretty large now. My retinue points limit was 9k which allowed me to have a 5k of retinues (heavy infantry mixed with cavalry and skirmish forces).

After the patch I see this on my retinue tab: "9K/3K", meaning I'm using 3 times more then I actually can. I wonder what changed so much and in which of the patches between 1.091 and 1.101. I tried searching change logs but I failed to find any descriptions of these changes.

Am I actually presumed to have 2k of soldiers when I control two very well upgraded duchies, and I'm a king of 3 kingdoms? Are these numbers ok or something just went wrong after the update?

Comment: I fixed the patch numbers and removed the "bonus" question at the end about resigning and score: it's not about retinues, and we have a one question per post policy. You're very welcome to post it as a separate question! We like new questions.

Answer (score 1):

In the patch notes:

> - Trade post garrisons now give less retinue cap increase

But I don't believe it would change that much.
Probably, you can blame your old savegame.

[You can read the entire patch notes here.](http://forum.paradoxplaza.com/forum/showthread.php?695290-Crusader-Kings-II-1.101-PATCH-RELEASED-Checksum-MEFB-NOT-for-problem-reports!)